# TypeError: Cannot read property "messageMetaData" from undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am writing AppScript to develop an Add On to allow user to move the current thread under a label. For the purpose of fetching current thread id.

**BuildAddOn(e)**

```
function buildAddOn(e) {
  // Activate temporary Gmail add-on scopes.
  var accessToken = e.messageMetaData.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(e.messageMetadata.accessToken);

  var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
```

While I try to run the function, the following error comes:

> TypeError: Cannot read property "messageMetaData" from undefined.
>   (line 3, file "Code")

Comment: Maybe you meant `messageMetadata`? Note that it's case sensitive

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the `buildAddOn` somewhere else in your code will cause the error. In this context, `e` is an object that will be passed only during initialization. And this is not equivalent to the object that you see in action handlers.

Sorry, if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. 
The fault was actually a typo.

Comment: No , after correcting the typo, when the buildAddOn(e) is run, the error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property "messageMetaData" from undefined " remains.
When I publish the add on by Deploy from manifest, the error:
"TypeError: Cannot read property "accessToken" from undefined." appears on the add on card.

Comment: Can you log `e` and check its contents?